# Dyamic Color Change of Ionic's ion-toggle and ion-checkbox (use color string at runtime)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to dynamically change the color of Ionic's Ion-Toggle and Ion-Checkbox at runtime. I know I can change it to a pre-defined sass variable like this:

```
<ion-toggle [color]="somePredefinedColor"></ion-toggle>
```

where "somePredefindedColor" is the string of the predefined sass variable...but because there is a section in my app that adapts to the corporate design colors of a company (which it gets from server as hex-strings) this is not possible.

The closest I got was to query the document by the component's class ".toggle-icon" and set its background color. This works at the first load but as soon as the page is loaded again it falls back to the sass predefined colors...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
<ion-toggle [style.color]="colorVariable"></ion-toggle>
```

Where `colorVariable` is a variable in your component in .ts file, which you can change it dynamically:

```
if (this.redCondition)
    this.colorVariable = 'red';
else
    this.colorVariale = 'black';
```

Alternatively, you can define two CSS classes in your SCSS file, call it red-toggle, and black-toggle. Then you can:

```
<ion-toggle [class.red-toggle]="redCondition" [class.black-toggle]="!redCondition"></ion-toggle>
```

These methods are called [style and class binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#style-binding) respectively.

If you want to dynamically change a value in your css style, you can use [ngStyle directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html):

```
 [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': hexColorString}"
```

**EDIT:**

The problem is that `ion-toggle` after transpile will have two child nodes, and you want to change the style of those child nodes dynamically. These nodes are toggle-icon, and toggle-inner:

[image]

This is not the cleanest way of doing it, but you can use the following typescript code, and modify it so that the colors change dynamically:

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('mytoggle').getElementsByTagName('div');
if(div1[0]){ 
   div1[0].style.backgroundColor = '#0F0';

   var div2 = div1[0].getElementsByTagName('div'); 
   if(div2[0])
     div2[0].style.backgroundColor = '#00F';
}
```

Notice that you have to set "mytoggle" as the id of the ion-toggle element in your html file.

**Disclaimer**: This code is rather hacky and may not work correctly with future versions of Ionic!

Comment: tried that very early. the second solution only works if I knew what colors to provide ahead - which will not always be the case... your first solution doesn't work because the "ion-toggle" component is made of it's own template and doesn't bind the style properties to its subobjects...

Comment: @MilanRubenKappen: I edited my answer. `ngStyle` should give you what you want.

Comment: You can change any other css property besides background-color

Comment: It would help if you post your code. One of these methods oaught to work.

Comment: actually boiled the code down to the very basic:
<ion-content><ion-toggle [ngStyle]="{'color': '#000', 'background-color': '#000'}"></ion-toggle></ion-content>

this leads to the following: [image of behaviour](http://b2a.mrkappen.com/weirdToggleBehaviour.png)

Comment: thanks for all your effort Ari but the problem with your solution remains: as soon as the page is reloaded (page with the toggle element moves to background and then foreground again) the whole thing refreshes and resets to the initial "primary"-sass-value... and then you can't even inject a new color value. i opened an issue on ionic's repo...

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this issue. You can create an event that is called each time you get the focus back and run my code, or use one of the lifecycle hooks, such as ionViewDidEnter: http://blog.ionic.io/navigating-lifecycle-events/

Comment: did use the ionViewDidEnter and tested if it is called every time. it is. that's why I don't get it - if I reenter the page -> leaving it and reentering the function is called but the colors fall back... really weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add square brackets on the dynamic attribute that is receiving the variable.

```
<ion-toggle [color]="somePredefinedColor"></ion-toggle>
```

Predefined colors can be setup in the `theme/variables.scss` file under `$colors`

```
$colors: (
   primary:#48B0F7,
   secondary:#10CFBD,
   ....
   somePredefinedColor:#000
)
```

Which can then be added to the `[color]` attribute

```
<ion-toggle [color]="somePredefinedColor"></ion-toggle>
```